# TextView initialisation in Android.

Tags: android, database, save

I developed an android application in which .. a data is entered and saved in database .... when the user click on this database details has to be displayed... for that I created textview ... but on click operation i cannot able to initialise what I have to do pls help .. i am copying th e code here pls help...

```
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

      for(Integer j=0; j<count; j++)

      {
          tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

          textView5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));


          textView6 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView6.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mname1")));

          textView7 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView7.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mname2")));

          textView8 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView8.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));

          textView9 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView9.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));

          textView5.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
          textView6.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
          textView7.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
          textView8.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
          textView9.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

          tableRow.addView(textView5);
          tableRow.addView(textView6);
          tableRow.addView(textView7);
          tableRow.addView(textView8);
          tableRow.addView(textView9);



          tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
          c.moveToNext();


        textView5.setClickable(true);

        textView5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String ett1 = textView5.getText().toString();/* Error is here*/
                String data1 = textView5.getText().toString();/*error is here*/


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , savedata.class);

                intent.putExtra("ett1", data1 + "");



                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

      }  










public class savedata extends Activity

{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.save_xm);

        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett1"));


}
}
```

Comment: u got the data from table ? and u wanna just display it right?

Comment: yes... and when user clicks on the table the value has to display...

Comment: ok how u what to display data ? in listview? textview??

Comment: I already created a new page ... that code I already given ...when user click on the database .. on the value ... it has to go to the next page and alll the details of user has to displayed in textview..

Comment: ok now tell me what is the issue that u r not undertsanding here

Comment: Actully my application is .. first page is to take users details firstname.. middle name email mob etc... and when he press save button this details are saved in database.. and when he presses the recall button the saved data is shown ... and when the user clicks on the value of any data.. all the details are viewed in another page ... so idid everything my pronblem i am not able to pass the value to next page textView5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     I created onclicklistner like this so when user press on textview 5 the value of textview has to pass to the nextpage...

Comment: ok cool ... u r going to next page via intent right?

Comment: ya that is right but the value of textview is not displayed in the next page... the value is users firstname

Comment: i mean to say when u r clicking the textView5 right how re u naiagting to next page?

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Activity :

Intent i=new Intent(Urclassname.this,secondPage.class);
i.putExtra("Id", stringdata);


In Next Page :(in onCreate Method)
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("Id");
```

Comment: this code is already there .... in my question ... the thing i cant able to pass the value of textview ...

Comment: the valueof textview5 has to be pass to next page

Comment: just get it by textview.getText()

Comment: can u post logcat plz

Comment: it is not working...because it cant do inside the onclick...i gave like textview5.getText().toString(); ... but error is showing

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable textView5 inside an inner class defined in a different method.... error is showing like this

Comment: ook got it first delare TextView as class variable and initlaze it in onCreate

Comment: ya...that is correct... so how i need to declare... i declared as null inside click function .. so in next page result is displayed as nulll.. I nee d to display the value of text view5 in next page...

Comment: declare TextView in class first : like this TextView tv; and in onCreate() -> tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.UrId); thats all

Comment: thats the problem... i dont know the UrId of textview.. I created textview like this... tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

          textView5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          textView5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));

Comment: can u pls tell how exactly i have to initialise it... textView5.setId(View.setTag(ID)); is it correct..?

Comment: yess right remeber that ur ID is variable and u have use that same for  findViewById

Comment: String ett1 = textView5.getText().toString();
        String data1 = textView5.getText().toString();   I did like this but is not working

Comment: can we chat somewhere?

Comment: sure ... my id is roshanpeter2002@gmail.com can u pls send a request